# Looping through difference sized arrays - avoiding 'Undefined offset' error

Tags: php

I'm working on a basic system to generate random word combinations.

I run one bit of SQL and get an array with results in, and another bit of SQL to get a 2nd array with a different set of words.

I loop through the first array, and join the first word from that with the corresponding word from the 2nd array.

Therefore, say I have these two arrays:

```
Array // referred to as `$list1

(
    [0] => yttrium
    [1] => yafty
    [2] => yard
    [3] => yellowknife
    [4] => yeasty
    [5] => york
    [6] => yo
    [7] => yemeles
    [8] => yo
    [9] => yellowstone
)

Array // referred to as `$list2

(
    [0] => yudding
    [1] => yudge
    [2] => yoody
    [3] => yeer
    [4] => yoisy
    [5] => yafty
    [6] => yine
    [7] => yuity
    [8] => yio
)
```

I loop through using this basic bit of code:

```
foreach ($list1 as $k => $v) {

    $words['output'][] = [
        'id' => $k,
        'value' => $v . '.' . $list2[$k]
    ];
}
```

Looking at the sample array above, the problem I have is if there are more elements in `list1` compared to in `list2` as I get this error:

```
Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\public_html\test.php on line 224
```

Where line 224 is this one:

```
'value' => $v . '.' . $list2[$k]
```

I have been trying to work out how to get around this - for example - by counting the size of the arrays, and if `list2` contains fewer elements than `list1` then only loop through `list1` as many times as there are elements in `list2`.

I was trying klunky solutions like:

```
$s1 = sizeof($list1);
$s2 = sizeof($list2);

if ($s2 < $s1) {
    $k = $s2;
} else {
    $k = $s1;
}

foreach ($list1 as $k => $v) {

    $words['output'][] = [
        'id' => $k,
        'value' => $v . '.' . $list2[$k]
    ];
}
```

However, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What should the output be if there is not a corresponding word in the second array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isset()` to test if the array element exists.

```
'value' => $v . '.' . (isset($list2[$k]) ? $list2[$k] : "")
```

Your code isn't working because you're not actually using the value of `$k` that you set. You're just overwriting it with the keys of `$list1`. The right way to write your second loop is:

```
foreach (array_slice($list1, 0, $k) as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

BTW, there's a built-in function for finding the smaller number: `$k = min($s1, $s2);`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - your advice helped me fix the issue. Thanks for the useful explanation and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could try only adding the element from the second array if it exists:

```
foreach ($list1 as $k => $v) {
    $value = $v;
    if (isset($list2[$k]) {
        $value .= '.' . $list2[$k];
    }
    $words['output'][] = [
        'id' => $k,
        'value' => $value
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `array_key_exists(value, array);` to determine if the key exists in both arrays within your loop

Try:

```
if(array_key_exists($k, $list2)){
    Do something if exists
}else{
    If doesn’t exist do something 
}
```